# Are events tables in BigQuery filled according to event_timestamp or server log time?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out the difference between tables in the events_intraday dataset in BigQuery and the events_ dataset. From what I understand, created_at in the events_param field is the server log time, so a table in the events_intraday table will have all events logged on that particular date, regardless of when they were fired.

But when I view event_timestamp in any events_ table, all of the events are from the same date itself. So my question is when an events_intraday table is transferred to events_ dataset, does BigQuery automatically transfer rows to the correct tables according to event_timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/real-time-exporting-of-analytics-data-into-bigquery.html), at the end of each day ( according to the developer's timezone), the `intraday`'s table will be moved to the permanent `appevents_` table (or events_table) and the old intraday table will be automatically cleaned up. For this reason, all the events which happened in the same day (current day) have the same `event_date`, thus will be moved to the same table.

Furthermore, Firebase exports the data to the `intraday` table in BigQuery as soon as it receives it. The [documentation](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/real-time-exporting-of-analytics-data-into-bigquery.html) states that the only two differences between the `events_` and `intraday_` tables are *lifetime value data and campaign information (the **traffic_source** record)*. You can check the BigQuery export's schema, [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?visit_id=1-636660162514047959-3257228354&rd=1&hl=en), in which it is described (among others) two columns:

```
Field name       Data type     Description
event_date        STRING        The date on which the event was logged (YYYYMMDD format in the registered timezone of your app).
event_timestamp   INTEGER       The time (in microseconds, UTC) at which the event was logged on the client.
```

Notice that both fields, `event_date` and `event_timestamp`, are recorded at the time/date on which the event was logged. In addition, you can also check this schema in BigQuery's UI using this public Firebase dataset `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.intraday_20181003`.Lastly, I would like to point that there isn't any field `created_at` in the export schema to BigQuery.